# How to put freichat script in as smarty template file

Tags: javascript, php, smarty, chat, messenger

I have How freichat chat script in php and want to integrate with custom php based site with smarty as template engine (View ). How to put that script in smarty template so it works?

Here is code for it...

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascipt" 
    src="http://server/freichat/client/main.php?id=<?php echo $ses;?>&xhash=<?php echo freichatx_get_hash($ses); ?>">
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="http://server/freichat/client/jquery/freichat_themes/freichatcss.php" 
    type="text/css">
```

Comment: `language` is depreciated, please stop using it.

Comment: that is not issue....its working well one custom php pages...i wann to run them on smary template files.